# 'Symbol not found' error when requiring node canvas module

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, canvas

I'm trying to get the node-canvas module working on my Mac, but as soon as I call `require('canvas')`, I receive this error:

```
Error: dlopen(/Users/james/projects/audiogram/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node, 1): Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFont
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.0.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.0.dylib
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:598:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/james/projects/audiogram/node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
```

I posted [an issue](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/928) on the node-canvas repo about this, but I haven't heard anything back yet.

```
Node 7.8.0
NPM 4.2.0
node-canvas 1.6.5
OSX 10.12.5
```

My specific question is: Why am I missing this symbol and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you fix it?? i also met it~

Comment: @lilyH ended up using [canvas-prebuilt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas-prebuilt).